# Como tirar o fundo num select option?

Tags: html, css

Tenho um `select option` com vários países eu criei o CSS para tirar o estilo padrão dele nos navegadores.

Estou com dois problemas, um preciso tirar aquele fundo azul quando passo por cima de cada opção preciso que fique só o texto e que sim ao mudar de opção mude a cor do texto só.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segundo problema e o `overflow` no google chrome não me aparece que e como eu pretendo, mas no firefox continua aparecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.select_pt {
  width: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}

.select_pt option {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.select_pt option:checked {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: blue;
}

.select_pt option:not(:checked) {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<select id="select_pt" class="select_pt" size="4">
    <option value="alemanha">Alemanha</option>
    <option value="austria">Áustria</option>
    <option value="belgica">Bélgica</option>
    <option value="bulgaria">Bulgária</option>
    <option value="chipre">Chipre</option>
    <option value="croacia">Croácia</option>
    <option value="dinamarca">Dinamarca</option>
    <option value="eslovaquia">Eslováquia</option>
    <option value="eslovenia">Eslovénia</option>
    <option value="espanha">Espanha</option>
    <option value="estonia">Estónia</option>
    <option value="finlandia">Finlândia</option>
    <option value="franca">França</option>
    <option value="grecia">Grécia</option>
    <option value="holanda">Holanda</option>
    <option value="hungria">Hungria</option>
    <option value="irlanda">Irlanda</option>
    <option value="italia">Itália</option>
    <option value="letonia">Letónia</option>
    <option value="lituania">Lituânia</option>
    <option value="luxemburgo">Luxemburgo</option>
    <option value="malta">Malta</option>
    <option value="polonia">Polónia</option>
    <option value="portugal" selected >Portugal</option>
    <option value="reino_unido">Reino Unido</option>
    <option value="republica_checa">Republica Checa</option>
    <option value="romenia">Roménia</option>
    <option value="suecia">Suecia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Mais porque você está usando as propriedades?

overflow-x :hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow: hidden;

Retire elas que o chrome vai criar o scroll automaticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Relativamente a alterar o fundo do `select` quando navega as opções, [não é possível fazê-lo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17742187/1242661).

No entanto, pode usar bibliotecas como o [select2](https://select2.github.io/) ou o [selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) para estilizar o `select` como desejar.

Segue um exemplo usando `select2`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('select').select2({width:100});
});
```

```css
.select2-results__options > li {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select>
    <option value="alemanha">Alemanha</option>
    <option value="austria">Áustria</option>
    <option value="belgica">Bélgica</option>
    <option value="bulgaria">Bulgária</option>
    <option value="chipre">Chipre</option>
    <option value="croacia">Croácia</option>
    <option value="dinamarca">Dinamarca</option>
    <option value="eslovaquia">Eslováquia</option>
    <option value="eslovenia">Eslovénia</option>
    <option value="espanha">Espanha</option>
    <option value="estonia">Estónia</option>
    <option value="finlandia">Finlândia</option>
    <option value="franca">França</option>
    <option value="grecia">Grécia</option>
    <option value="holanda">Holanda</option>
    <option value="hungria">Hungria</option>
    <option value="irlanda">Irlanda</option>
    <option value="italia">Itália</option>
    <option value="letonia">Letónia</option>
    <option value="lituania">Lituânia</option>
    <option value="luxemburgo">Luxemburgo</option>
    <option value="malta">Malta</option>
    <option value="polonia">Polónia</option>
    <option value="portugal" selected >Portugal</option>
    <option value="reino_unido">Reino Unido</option>
    <option value="republica_checa">Republica Checa</option>
    <option value="romenia">Roménia</option>
    <option value="suecia">Suecia</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é isso que queres porém creio que a parte de alterar apenas a cor do texto quando o mouse passa por cima acho que funcionaria com o [Hover](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/csslinks.php).

```
.select_pt:hover {
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Porém a parte do Overflow não sei informar ao certo o que pode ser.

Edição

```
.select_pt option:checked {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: O meu prolema de aparecer esse fundo nao e ao passar o mouse por cima mas sim quando clico numa opção fica esse fundo ou entao ao mudar as opções pelas setas do teclado aparece sempre esse fundo

Comment: @CésarSousa entendi errado desculpe, creio que então na parte onde esta o `checked` deves trocar o backgroud pela cor que deseja, irei atualizar a resposta para mostrar

Comment: fiz isso mas mantem sempre o azul nao muda para branco eu quero que fique sem nehnhum fundo que passe as opcoes mas que mostro so o texto

Comment: @CésarSousa Supostamente do jeito que mostrei ele mostraria um fundo branco porém não entendo o porque não funcionou, farei uns testes e verei

Comment: isto e estranho porque se eu tirar do select o size="5" ele ja fica sem fundo porem so mostra uma opcao assim e eu quero que mostre varias como tem na imagem

Comment: @CésarSousa cara eu testei aqui e não tem lógica o porque fica marcado de azul mesmo tirando todas as opções de "azul" do código

Comment: <select id="select_pt" class="select_pt" size="4"> se eu tirar esse size="4" fica sem fundo com ele tem fundo tambem nao vejo logica mas e o que acontece

Comment: mas haver se percebes-te o fundo so aparece mesmo quando escolha a opção a select em si nao tem fundo isso eu consegui aparece e um fundo no texto da opção quando a escolho

Comment: Ao retirar o `size="4"` a opção que dei funciona quando uma option é **Selecionada** ela fica com o fundo branco porem preciso verificar ao mudar com as setas do mouse @CésarSousa

Comment: Vou testar isso não testei ao tirar o size 4 mas se tirar esse size só mostra uma opção e eu quero que mostre mais que uma opção como na imagem a ideia do size e essa percebe

Comment: @CésarSousa Chegou a testar?

Comment: sim ja testei quando selecionada uma opção aparece so o texto da opção sem fundo sem nada mas tambem so aparece uma opção

Comment: Certo então é tipo isso que quer né? só que com 4 linhas e quando passa o mouse e move com as teclas tbm não apareca nada no background @CésarSousa ?

Comment: certo isso mesmo como esta na imagem mas sem aquele fundo que tirando o size faz isso mas so fica com uma opção a mostra e eu preciso como esta na imagem

Comment: @CésarSousa Agora ja não sei mais o que fazer pois até com o hover não funcionou

Comment: Não sei porque o size faz isso